# Getting different answers for an integral: $\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}\ln{|x+2|}+C$ vs $\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}\ln{|2x+4|}+C$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

Problem:

> $$\int\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{2x+4}dx$$

Using two different methods I am getting two different answers and have trouble finding why.

Method 1:

$$\int\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{2x+4}dx$$

$$\int\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+2}\right)dx$$
$$\int\frac{1}{2}dx-\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{1}{x+2}dx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{1}{x+2}dx$$
$$x+2=u$$
$$dx=du$$
$$\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{1}{u}du$$

> $$\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}\ln{|x+2|}+C$$

Method 2:
$$\int\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{2x+4}dx$$

$$\int\frac{1}{2}-3\left(\frac{1}{2x+4}\right)dx$$
$$\int\frac{1}{2}dx-3\int\frac{1}{2x+4}dx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}x-3\int\frac{1}{2x+4}dx$$
$$2x+4=u$$
$$dx=\frac{du}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{1}{u}du$$

> $$\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}\ln{|2x+4|}+C$$

Comment: Note that $\left| 2x+4 \right| = 2 \left| x+2 \right|$ and then use the properties of logarithms to see that the factor of 2 is essentially just a constant in addition.

Comment: As others have mentioned, your issue is resolved by a logarithm property. ... Often, the trickiest part of learning Calculus is remembering your *Pre*-Calculus. :)

Comment: This type of question, like find the difference between
$\int (x+1 )dx=\frac{x^2}{2}+x+C$ and $\int (x+1)dx=\frac{(x+1)^2}{2}+C$, appears here so frequently, and the answer is always the same (there are no difference, only the constants differs). Can a canonical answer be made for it?

Comment: Further to @Zacky's point, in some cases it's as simple as "they're clearly the same" (up to a constant or otherwise), but sometimes proving the equivalence requires e.g. a trigonometric identity the OP doesn't know how to prove. I'm not sure whether that means we should have multiple "canonical" versions or just give up on trying it altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both answers are the same, mind the constant:
$$\ln|2x+4|+\color{blue}{C_1}=\ln|2\left(x+2\right)|+\color{blue}{C_1}=\ln|x+2|+ \underbrace{\ln 2 + \color{blue}{C_1}}_{\color{purple}{C_2}} = \ln|x+2|+\color{purple}{C_2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\frac12 x + \frac 32 \ln |2x + 4| + C_1 &= \frac12x + \frac32\ln(2\cdot|x+2|) + C_1\\&=\frac12x + \frac32(\ln 2 + \ln|x+2|)+C_1\\&=\frac12x + \frac32 \ln|x+2| + (\frac 32 \ln 2 + C_1)\\&=\frac12x + \frac32\ln|x+2| + C_2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\ln|2x+4|=\ln|2(x+2)|=\ln|2|+\ln|x+2|=\ln|x+2|+C$